# Generate PuTTY PPK v3 file version programmatically in C# with HMAC-SHA-256

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, putty, sha256

I tried this code: https://antonymale.co.uk/generating-putty-key-files.html

It works OK with PPK version with SHA-1, the file and private-mac generates OK and I'm able to connect to my server.

Now, I have to update my code to work with PPK v3 and HMAC-SHA-256, and I read the documentation and took a look through the source code. It seems that what changed is the MAC derivation key.

```
public class PuttyKeyFileGenerator
{
    private const int prefixSize = 4;
    private const int paddedPrefixSize = prefixSize + 1;
    private const int lineLength = 64;
    private const string keyType = "ssh-rsa";
    private const string encryptionType = "none";

    public static string RSAToPuttyPrivateKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider, string comment = "imported-key")
    {
        RSAParameters keyParameters = cryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);

        byte[] publicBuffer = new byte[3 + keyType.Length + paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.Exponent.Length +
                                       paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.Modulus.Length + 1];

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(publicBuffer)))
        {
            writer.Write(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
            writer.Write(keyType);
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.Exponent, true);
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.Modulus, true);
        }
        string publicBlob = Convert.ToBase64String(publicBuffer);

        byte[] privateBuffer = new byte[paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.D.Length + paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.P.Length +
                                        paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.Q.Length + paddedPrefixSize + keyParameters.InverseQ.Length];

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(privateBuffer)))
        {
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.D, true);
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.P, true);
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.Q, true);
            WritePrefixed(writer, keyParameters.InverseQ, true);
        }
        string privateBlob = Convert.ToBase64String(privateBuffer);

        byte[] bytesToHash = new byte[prefixSize + keyType.Length + prefixSize + encryptionType.Length + prefixSize + comment.Length +
                                      prefixSize + publicBuffer.Length + prefixSize + privateBuffer.Length];

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(bytesToHash)))
        {
            WritePrefixed(writer, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyType));
            WritePrefixed(writer, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptionType));
            WritePrefixed(writer, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(comment));
            WritePrefixed(writer, publicBuffer);
            WritePrefixed(writer, privateBuffer);
        }

        var hmacsha = new HMACSHA256(new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("")));
        string hash = String.Join("", hmacsha.ComputeHash(bytesToHash).Select(x => String.Format((string) "{0:x2}", (object) x)));

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("PuTTY-User-Key-File-3: " + keyType);
        sb.AppendLine("Encryption: " + encryptionType);
        sb.AppendLine("Comment: " + comment);

        var publicLines = SpliceText(publicBlob, lineLength).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine("Public-Lines: " + publicLines.Length);
        foreach (var line in publicLines)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        var privateLines = SpliceText(privateBlob, lineLength).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine("Private-Lines: " + privateLines.Length);
        foreach (var line in privateLines)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }

        sb.AppendLine("Private-MAC: " + hash);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I tried to change the MAC part with this (I'm not using any encryption mode):

```
var hmacsha = new HMACSHA256(new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("")));
string hash = String.Join("", hmacsha.ComputeHash(bytesToHash).Select(x => String.Format((string) "{0:x2}", (object) x)));
```

But it seems that MAC is incorrectly computed.

I tried several other approaches to generate my keys or to start `bytesToHash` from string and then convert that value to bytes, but still is not working.

Do you have any idea how to compute the Private-Mac with HMAC256?

Answer (score 1):

The correct response is this one:

```
var hmac = new HMACSHA256(new byte[0]);
string hash = String.Join("", hmac.ComputeHash(bytesToHash).Select(x => String.Format((string)"{0:x2}", (object)x)));
```